# how to prove $E(X|\mathcal G)(\omega)=n\int^{\frac{j}{n}}_{\frac{j-1}{n}}X(s)ds, \omega\in(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}].$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose $\Omega=[0,1]$, and $\mathcal P=$lebesgue Measure , and $\mathcal F=\mathcal B([0,1])$
and also Suppose X is random variable and $\mathcal G$ is $\sigma-$algebra Produced With intervals $ (\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}]$   $\forall j=1,2,...,n$      .

show that $E(X|\mathcal G)(\omega)=n\int^{\frac{j}{n}}_{\frac{j-1}{n}}X(s)ds, \omega\in(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}].$

thanks in advance

$\mathcal B$ means Borel $\sigma-$algebra.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor technicality: We need $\{0\} $ in the collection of sets from which ${\cal G}$ is created, otherwise ${\cal G}$ would not be a sub-$\sigma$-field of ${ \cal F}$.

Let $I_0 = \{0\}$, and let $I_j$ be the intervals above. Then it is straightforward to show that ${\cal G} = \sigma \{I_j\} = \{ \cup_{j \in J} I_j  | J \text{ is finite }\}$ (the empty union being $\emptyset$).

Let $Y$ be the formula to the right of $E( X | {\cal G})$ above, and note that $Y$ is simple. It is straightforward to verify that $Y$ is ${\cal G}$ measurable and  $\int_{I_j} Y = \int_{I_j} X$ for all $I_j$. (Since $P\{0\} = 0$, we have $\int_{I_0} Y = \int_{I_0} X$.)

Let ${\cal C} = \{ C \in {\cal G} | \int_{C} Y = \int_{C} X \}$. Then we have $I_j \in {\cal C}$ for all  $I_j$, and since the $I_j$ are disjoint, it follows immediately that $\cup_{j \in J} I_j \in {\cal G}$ for any finite $J$. Hence ${\cal C} = {\cal G}$.

It follows that $Y$ is a version of $E( X | {\cal G})$.

(Since $\{0\}$ is the only null set other than $\emptyset$, we can see that **all** versions of $E( X | {\cal G})$ have the form $Y+c\cdot 1_{\{0\}}$, where $c$ is some constant.)

Comment: Excuse me
I was wrong.

Comment: You should do what you want to do, I just would like to understand the why :-).

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb E\big(X\,|\,\mathcal G)$ can be defined as the *unique* $\mathcal G$-measurable function $Y$ s.t.
$$\tag{P}
\mathbb E \big( XZ \big) = \mathbb E \big( YZ \big)
$$
for any $\mathcal G$-measurable funcion $Z$ s.t. the expected value $\mathbb E \big( XZ \big)$ exists.

That said, basically we have to check 2 things:

**1.** if
$$
Y(\omega) = \sum_{j=1}^nn\int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac jn} \!\!X(s){\rm d}s ~~\chi_{(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac jn]}(\omega)
$$
is $\mathcal G$-measurable (I compactly rewrote your function using the [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) $\chi$ notation)

**2.** and if the property **(P)** holds.

No. **1.** is easy to check: to be more specific, note that since the intervals that generate the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G$ make a finite partition of the whole set $[0,1]$, then any set of $\mathcal G$ is the union of some of those *atoms*, and viceversa any such set belongs to $\mathcal G$. Therefore any $\mathcal G$-measurable function is a (step) function which is constant over those intervals (otherwise the preimages wouldn't belong to $\mathcal G$, can you see it?)

As to point no. **2.**, by linearity (and by the fact that those intervals $\sigma$-generate $\mathcal G$), it suffices to show that the property **(P)** holds for the characteristic functions
$$
Z_j(\omega) = \chi_{(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac jn]}(\omega)~,\quad j=1\ldots n
$$

Try and check it...

### Otherwise...

As to **2.**, instead of checking if that specific function works, you can directly find it yourself. As stated above, being $\mathcal G$-measurable, the expected value we are looking for is a step function
$$
\mathbb E\big( X\,|\,\mathcal G\big)(\omega) = \sum_{j=1}^n c_j\,\chi_{(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac jn]}(\omega) ~\quad\exists\,\, c_1\ldots c_n\in\mathbb R
$$
Therefore we just have to find those coefficients $c_1\ldots c_n$. As previously suggested, let us check what happens with the functions $Z_j$:
$$\tag{1}
\int_{[0,1]}\mathbb E\big( X\,|\,\mathcal G\big)(\omega)\,Z_j(\omega)\,{\rm d}\omega
~=~
\int_{[0,1]}
\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\,\chi_{(\frac{i-1}{n},\frac in]}(\omega)}_{\mathbb E\big( X\,|\,\mathcal G\big)(\omega)}\,
\underbrace{\chi_{(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac jn]}(\omega)}_{Z_j(\omega)}\,{\rm d}\omega
~=\\
c_j\int_{(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac jn]} {\rm d}\omega ~=~ \frac{c_j}{n}
$$
Now, for property **(P)** this has to be equal to
$$\tag{2}
\int_{[0,1]} X(\omega)\,Z_j(\omega)\,{\rm d}\omega
~=~
\int_{(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac jn]} X(\omega){\rm d}\omega
$$
Now compare **(1)** and **(2)**...

Comment: The conditional expectation is not, in general, unique.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's $\mathcal P$-a.e. unique, that is why sometimes we talk about _versions_. Wherever integration is involved I rather consider two functions to be equal if they coincide a.e..